# HttpHandler never getting called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha, httphandler

I have an MVC application that I'm trying to add the ManagedFusion.Web.Captcha.CaptchaImageHandler into so that I can write the following code :

```
<label for="captcha">Enter @Html.Raw(Business.Captcha.CaptchaImage(Html, 50, 180))  Below</label>
```

and have the image appear.  The code for that class is just cut and paste from the examples online:

```
public static string CaptchaImage(this HtmlHelper helper, int height, int width) {
            ManagedFusion.Web.Controls.CaptchaImage image = new ManagedFusion.Web.Controls.CaptchaImage {
                Height = height,
                Width = width,
            };
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(image.UniqueId, image,
                null,
                DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(ManagedFusion.Web.Controls.CaptchaImage.CacheTimeOut),
                Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                null);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);
            stringBuilder.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"captcha-guid\" value=\"");
            stringBuilder.Append(image.UniqueId);
            stringBuilder.Append("\" />");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine();
            stringBuilder.Append("<img src=\"");
            stringBuilder.Append("/captcha.ashx?guid=" + image.UniqueId);
            stringBuilder.Append("\" alt=\"CAPTCHA\" width=\"");
            stringBuilder.Append(width);
            stringBuilder.Append("\" height=\"");
            stringBuilder.Append(height);
            stringBuilder.Append("\" />");
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

I've added the following to my web.config

```
<system.web>

<httpHandlers>
  <add  verb="GET" path="test.sample"  type="ManagedFusion.Web.Handlers.CaptchaImageHandler, ManagedFusion.Web.Captcha" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >

</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="CaptchaImageHandler" verb="GET" path="captcha.ashx"  type="ManagedFusion.Web.Handlers.CaptchaImageHandler, ManagedFusion.Web.Captcha" />
</handlers>
```

All previous SO questions point to the system.web->httpHandlers getting picked up by Cassini and the system.webServer->handlers getting picked up by IIS 7.  But whenever I navigate to the view that has the aforementioned code, I always get a 404 for the /captcha.ashx.  There is no route ignore rule in the global.asax.  What is going on here?  It's like nothing I do will get the handler to fire either on my local machine or on a deployed IIS 7 instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Global.asax file, I needed to add the ignore route before the default route mapping, so the whole method looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.Ignore("captcha.ashx");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```